# Swagger-ui doesn't provide how i pass MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM content

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Actually i am facing a problem that **Swagger-ui** can't show me input for **MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM**, so lets imagine this next service:

> @PUT
>
> @Path("/performAudioQuery")
>
> @Consumes(**MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM**)
>
> public Response performAudioQuery(**InputStream audioInputStream**){
>       //Impl of the service
>   }

and here are the dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and i am using wildfly 9.x
So what should i do to make it possible for Swagger-ui working good with this previous service?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the Swagger/OpenAPI specification (2.0) doesn't deal kindly with file uploads as what's known as body parameter. We've formulated a workable solution that is covered at https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/50 - however that solution is currently not fully supported by swagger-core and not supported at all in swagger-ui.